# List of all the Jenkins Build Steps and Post Build Actions

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have been looking for a list that contains all of the "Add build step" and "Add post-build action". Here's what I have so far:

Add build steps

```
Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild
Execute Windows batch command
Execute shell
Invoke Ant
Invoke Gradle script
Invoke top-level Maven targets
Run with timeout
Set build status to "pending" on GitHub commit
```

Add post-build actions

```
Aggregate downstream test results
Archive the artifacts
Build other projects
Publish JUnit test result report
Publish Javadoc
Publish MSTest test result report
Publish NUnit test result report
Record Emma coverage report
Record fingerprints of files to track usage
Git Publisher
Publish Cucumber reports generated with handlebars
Publish JUnit reports generated with handlebars
Publish RSpec reports generated with handlebars
Publish TestNG reports generated with handlebars
Copy files back to the job's workspace on the master node
E-mail Notification
Editable Email Notification
Publish to Subversion repository
Reverts commits that breaks the build
Set GitHub commit status (universal)
Set build status on GitHub commit [deprecated]
Delete workspace when build is done
```

Am I missing any? And is there a list that organizes them this way?

Apologies in advance if this is a dumb question...

Comment: Build Steps and Post-build actions comes from the plugins that has been installed in a Jenkins instance.  For example all the GitHub related action in the Post-build actions comes because of the GitHub plugin. There is no definite list for the number of Build steps or Post-build actions, it depends upon the plugins you install. However, when you install Jenkins it comes with few default Build steps and Post-build actions.

Comment: Why are you willing to compile such a list?

Comment: Thanks ANIL, in doing a little more research I see that you may even create your own plugins. 

Joep, I wanted to compile a list of default plugins that can be downloaded to see what functions were available without having to create it manually. To gain an overview of the available options.